# How do I move the grouped buttons to the center of the navbar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I'm trying to make the links appear in the center and when I resize the page to show on mobile I want them to be placed next to each other.

Now there's 3 big blocks on top of each other on mobile. These have to be next to each other and smaller.

[image]

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="row">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="/scan-qr" class="active">QR-Scanner</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#home" class="active">QR-Scanner</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="#home" class="active">QR-Scanner</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the code I provided you can see the code of the html page and de CSS. The images contain the view of the mobile version and how it looks on a normal browser on my laptop.

Comment: you forgot images

Comment: @user3532758 Sorry, I added them to the top of the question

Comment: your html is invalid - your li need to be inside a ul.  Also as you are using boostrap, you need to have a col inside your row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="row">
      <li class="nav-link col-md-4"> <a href="/scan-qr" class="active">QR-Scanner</a> </li> 
      <li class="nav-link col-md-4"> <a href="#home" class="active">QR-Scanner</a> </li> 
      <li class="nav-link col-md-4"> <a href="#home" class="active">QR-Scanner</a> </li> 
    </u>
    </div>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is incorrect.

There is no nav and ul tag, and your class navbar is in the wrong place.

Your list should be:

```
<nav class="navbar">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="/scan-qr" class="active">QR-Scanner</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-link">
           <a href="#home" class="active">QR-Scanner</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-link">
           <a href="#home" class="active">QR-Scanner</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Next, you need to change styles in your responsive CSS.

```
.navbar-nav{
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-link{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the reference:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Cheers.